# in intellij-idea "package cern.jet.random does not exist"

Tags: intellij-idea

i get this error in intellij-idea 9 . "package cern.jet.random does not exist"
what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a package in the [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) library.  Once you download the jar, you can and add it to your project.

Comment: i did what u said but i have the same error. I added the colt.jar to my lib.but i get the same error

i changed name of colt.jar to colt.zip and i opened it and the favorite path was there and i dont know what's the problem now.and in intellij i dont know why but there is not a > left side of colt.jar but there is a > left side of other libs.